# Should we use Interface Builder in need of dynamically created UI?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, interface-builder, dynamic-ui

I'm currently thinking of project, which is basically interpreting data from many abstract data sources.

So the communication within application is like this

```
[UI] <-> [Controller / Delegate] <-> [Subclass of Abstract Data Source]
```

which is basically the MVC pattern. What is my problem, that each `[Subclass of Abstract Data Source]` can use only limited amount of `[UI]`, so the flow is basically this:

- Create instance of Data Source (DS)
- Get list of possible UI's from DS
- Create UI chooser and instantiate preset UI
- Let DS modify UI
- Fill UI from DS by predefined handler method

Example UI's are `NSTableView`, `NSOutlineView`, `NSCollectionView`, etc.

So I basically need to change column names, order, style of controls, ... without possibility of having unique NSWindow designed for each `Data Source`

Now the question:

**If I need dynamic UI creation and custom data handling logic (no bindings to Core Data, or so), should I (and is it even possible to) use InterfaceBuilder or should I implement all view logic programatically?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use whichever you favor. Any variations/dynamic areas can be represented/handled by the *controllers*. In a way, that means that I recommend moving the *dynamic* portions to code to controllers -- but you can still use XIBs for common high level design, if you choose.

Therefore, when a view is not suitable for a singular data representation and is used for multiple, the implementation/variations can be moved to the controller domain. When an implementation/definition applies to all, then you can define that in the XIB or in the program -- wherever you prefer to put it. In that case, you can use XIBs (or code) for invariant (skeletal) views.